# Stop Scrolling at a Certain Point

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replicate something similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1/) .

When you scroll down, the div scrolls with you (`position: fixed`) until it reaches a certain point, where it stops (`position: absolute`), and as you continue to scroll down, it retains that position on the page (`250px`), until you scroll up to pick it back up again.

[What I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/JaJ5Q/).

Right now my fiddle does everything except it does not retain the position it was "dropped off" at, instead it goes back to its original position.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the scrollTop value of the window and then apply that as the value for top and set position to absolute.

```
$('element').css({
    'top': $(window).scrollTop(),
    'position': 'absolute'
});
```

As you keep scrolling though the scrollTop value will change, so you must only do this once. Use a variable to keep track of what state the element is in. As far as I can tell, there are three:

1. Relative
2. Fixed
3. Absolute

With this variable you can also reduce the strain on the browser by only setting a class when it is needed. For example:

```
if( y > 100 && pos != 'fixed' ){

    pos = 'fixed';

    $('element').addClass('fixed');

}else if( y > 100 && pos != 'relative' ){

    pos = 'relative';

    $('element').addClass('relative');

}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I made the following change of:

```
if (y >= socialTop & y <= 150) {
    $('#static-social').addClass('fixed');
} else {
    $('#static-social').removeClass('fixed');
}
```

To:

```
if (y >= socialTop & y <= 150) {
    $('#static-social').css('marginTop', $(this).scrollTop());
}
```

This ensured that the element stayed at the top of the page based on the position of the window, so when you scroll back up it's left where it was.

Comment: This is a very slow and intensive way of doing things. You're basically replacing the browsers native position:fixed abilities with javascript. Reminds me when we had to do this for ie6.